# MD5sum of filename containing white spaces

Tags: bash, shell, md5sum

I'm trying to get the md5sum of every file of a directory, in this format :

```
hashcode  dir/path/to/file
```

I'm using :

```
md5sum $(find /path/to/dir -type f | sort)
```

but this doesn't work if the file as a white space in its name.

And adding apostrophes: `md5sum "$(find /path/to/dir -type f | sort)"`  doesn't seems to solve the problem (it only print the path, not the md5 anymore).

Comment: What is `dirName`?

Comment: Try `find /path/to/dir -type f -exec md5sum {} +`

Comment: @Cedric No, there is still one `dirName` in your question. And `/path/to/dir -type f` does not really make sense, does it?

Comment: okay, i just realize i forgot a part of the command, now it should make more sense

Comment: @M.NejatAydin solution works. but is it possible to 'sort' it ?

Comment: Yes, `find /path/to/dir -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k2`

Comment: that works. something i don't get is this comand dosen't give me the sames md5 as  `data=dir.tar.gz; paste     <(tar xzf "$data" --to-command=md5sum)     <(tar tzf "$data" | grep -v '/$')| sed 's/-\t//'^C`   looks to me that it's doing the same thing while it untar. it's the same output, but with different md5, why ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin sorting only the second field like that won't work because the **files have spaces in their names** which will be split into different fields. You need to sort the whole thing after the first field

Comment: @Cedric the output of that command results in the same MD5 hashes as other methods in my PC

Comment: @phuclvp No, it will work. `-k2` doesn't mean "sort only on the second field", which `-k2,2` would mean. `-k2` defines a key field that begins at the second field and ends at the last character of the line.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet it makes sense: search all files beginning at dir /path/to/dir.

Comment: `"` is a (double) quote, not apostrophe which is `'`, or more correctly single quote in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder has only one layer deep then simply let the shell expand file names like this

```
md5sum *
```

If there are more layers then you can enable [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and the output will [still be sorted](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) as expected

```
shopt -s globstar
md5sum ** 2>/dev/null
```

Alternatively use `find` directly

```
find -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum
```